# Unable to locate react static files when serving from django staticfiles and uploading to heroku

Tags: python, reactjs, django, heroku

I'm trying to add a Django backend and a react frontend to Heroku. Following [this tutorial](https://dev.to/mdrhmn/deploying-react-django-app-using-heroku-2gfa). I'm using whitenoise for serving static files.

When runnning `python manage.py collectstatic` I keep getting the same error:

```
django.core.exceptions.SuspiciousFileOperation: The joined path (C:\Users\<name>\Documents\combined_connect\static\media\background-pattern.f6347303.png) is located outside of the base path component (C:\Users\<name>\Documents\combined_connect\staticfiles)
```

This command is also run by heroku python hooks when deploying. The python hook runs after the react hook, so the react build folder is definitely there. For testing purposes I also ran `build` locally for when I call the `collectstatic` command.

The problem is something to do with how I'm defining static roots, but for the life of me I can't figure it out. I've used multiple tutorials, the django docs on static files, and the heroku dev docs on static files.

Why is it looking for my media files (background-pattern.png etc.) in static? On `collectstatic` everything gets put into the `staticfiles` directory. No matter what I change the file names or variables to, that error about the lookup conflict between `staticfiles` and `static` always happens.

Here's how I'm defining them:

settings.py

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
​

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'build')], # pointing to the React build folder
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = 'build/static/'
​
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'build/static'),
)
```

Here's how the project is structured:

[image]

EDIT: Using this config, I can serve the backend just fine. If I go to the root url `/`, I see the Django 404 page instead o my React homepage. Going to `/admin` works perfectly, and I can call `/api/` endpoints.

Comment: Here is an answer for the same question like yours - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37241902/django-joined-path-is-located-outside-of-the-base-path-component-static-img

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First maybe some clarification :-)

The "Media" directory is used for content uploaded for example by a user. So it's more a dynamic content, not static. Or at least not static with every instance of your service. Therefore it's usually also not shipped with your application. Details in the [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/files/)

Also check [settings documentation about MEDIA_ROOT](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#media-root)

I assume in your settings you something like `MEDIA_ROOT = "build/static/media/"` or something similar, which results in the conflict.

If you want to use "media" files, hence user uploaded files, you need a different storage on Heroku anyway. Heroku Dynos have a [ephemeral filesystem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem) which means you get a fresh copy of your instance once a day, which results in loss of all that data you stored during the life-time of the instance.

To solve this this problem you can store those media files for example on AWS S3.
Django has an awesome [addon](https://pypi.org/project/django-s3-storage/0.11.1/), which replaces the filesystem storage with AWS S3 storage. Which means the API from your point of you as a Developer does not change at all.

Here is a Django Development and PROD setting example with django-s3-storage:

Development example config (nothing special, no S3):

```
class Development(Configuration):

    ... # Your code

    @property
    def MEDIA_ROOT(self):
        default_value = os.path.join(self.BASE_DIR, 'public', 'media')
        return values.Value(default=default_value, environ_name='MEDIA_ROOT')


    @property
    def STATIC_ROOT(self):
        default_value = os.path.join(self.BASE_DIR, 'static')
        return values.Value(default=default_value, environ_name='STATIC_ROOT')

    @property
    def STATICFILES_DIRS(self):
        return (
            os.path.join(self.BASE_DIR, 'whatever', 'react', 'build'),
            os.path.join(self.BASE_DIR, 'yourapp', 'admin', 'static'),
        )
    ... # Your code
```

For your local development make SURE media and static do not point to the same directory/structure.

Production example config:

```
# Inheriting from Development only serves as example. Good practice would be to move code used by both environments into a `Base` class. 
class Production(Development):
    ... # Your code

    DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'django_s3_storage.storage.S3Storage'

    AWS_REGION = "us-east-1"

    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = values.Value(default='', environ_name='AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = values.Value(default='', environ_name='AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
    AWS_S3_BUCKET_NAME = values.Value(default='', environ_name='AWS_S3_BUCKET_NAME')

    @property
    def INSTALLED_APPS(self):
        return super().INSTALLED_APPS + [
            'django_s3_storage',
        ]

    ... # Your code
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation. Will only have time to test this on the weekend, but will be sure to test it before the bounty expires.

Comment: No rush... I don't care about the bounty. It just happened that I deployed a project on Heroku using Django/React some time ago and faced similar issues with media / static files.

Comment: Didn't get a chance to test this in the end, but it's a very detailed answer that I'm sure will prove very useful to anyone who finds their way here. Marked it as correct as others have also upvoted it.